# Hibernate result set_ object data mapping

Tags: hibernate

When I use 
"sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from table").list();"

I get the below json data

```
---"{"records":"3","total":null,"rows":[{"appname":"frg","bl":"dfh","subbl":"jhf","appmanager":"fd","nrun":3,"isblore":"dfh","isupdated":"Yes","plandate":"2013-09-15","createdate":"2013-09-15","updateddate":1379919600000,"appcontact":"hg","id":4,"priority":"dfb"},--"
```

with column and value

Where as when i try    `"sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(" select appname,bl,subbl.....from table").list();"`

I get the below json data

```
---"{"records":"3","total":null,"rows":[[4,"frg","dfh","jhf","dfb","fd",3,"hg","Yes","dfh",1379228400000,1379919600000],"page":null} "
```

Due to which I am not able to display my data in the jgrid.

Kindly let me know how to overcome this issue of object mapping.